# "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized." with json file

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, connection-string

I'm trying to get the connectionstring from the json-file to the DAL-class library with:

```
private static IConfigurationRoot config;
private static string connectionString;

public UserDAL()
{
    config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
    connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("DefaultString");
}
```

In the json-file:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultString": "theconnectionstring"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

The error happens when I try to open the connection, so `con.Open();`

Comment: It looks like your code accessing the config is correct. Why are you instantiating an IConfiguration in the constructor? You should be receiving it as a constructor parameter via DI.

Comment: what is DI? And I instantiate is in the constructor so when a UserDAL is created than it can use the config, else there's no use for accessig the json file...I think

Comment: DI = Dependency Injection. It's where you define your dependencies as constructor parameters, and the DI container builds your object. Basically @Fabjan answered this.

Comment: The code of accessing the configuration and getting the connectionString is ok.Where and what is your code to open the connection?